# devuelve null en expresiones regulares

Tags: javascript, regex

Construyo una expresión regular para localizar una porción de texto:

```
var re = /Incident:(.*)\tDescriptio/gm; 
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(resultados_texto)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }

}
```

donde `resultados_texto` es una variable de tipo `string` a la que le he dado el contenido de un archivo de texto.

quiero obtener el contenido del grupo 1, es decir, todo lo contenido en `(.*)`

El problema es que creo que la sintaxis está bien construida, pero me devuelve que `m` es `null`

Cual es el fallo en la sintaxis ?

Comment: Pero en ese código no esta `resultados_texto` definida.

Comment: Puedes dar un ejemplo de `resultados_texto`?

Comment: El resultado de `re.exec` es un array, asi que `m.index` es `undefined`.

Comment: resultados_texto es un string :

Comment: Es el valor de una variable que he definido anteriormente y su contenido el un texto de muchas lineas. Es decir en el mismo archivo -js defino la variable resultados_texto y en ella meto el contenido de un archivo local .txt Luego con la expresión regular quiero obtener una cadena contenida en resultados_texto. Pero incluso cuando abro la consola si me muestra el valor de la variable resultados_texto, pero m me devuelve null. No se si es que no obtiene el valor por la expresión regular o que la variable m es local.

Comment: Puedes agregar un ejemplo de _resultados_texto_ para poder reproducir el error?

Answer (score 1):

Funciona en mi navegador: (abre la consola -F12- para ver los resultados)

```js
var re = /Incident:(.*)\tDescriptio/gm; 
var m;

var resultados_texto = "Incident: este es el texto a buscar\tDescription:lo_que sea 140116 Drift Start Time: 14/01/2016 6:00:00 Grid File: prueba.gd";

while ((m = re.exec(resultados_texto)) !== null) {
   console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es que en lugar de "Incident:12345\tDescription" poder introducir la variable resultados_texto que ya he definido antes y que su valor es el contenido de un archivo de texto, osea, un string

Comment: @kamome puedes agregar un ejemplo simple del valor de resultados_texto?

Comment: Incident: este es el texto a buscar Description:lo_que sea 140116
 Drift Start Time: 14/01/2016 6:00:00
 Grid File: prueba.gd..........

Comment: @kamome con ese texto funciona únicamente si agrego \t, ya que la regular expression lo busca.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que tengas un salto de línea dentro del texto, y el punto en `.*` [coincide con cualquier caracter menos los saltos de línea](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-dot) (por eso convenía que pusieras un ejemplo en la pregunta). En otros motores de expresiones regulares, esto se resuelve fácilmente seteando el modo `DOTALL` (o `single-line`), sin embargo en JavaScript no está implementado. Para resolverlo, se usa un "truco": en vez de un punto, se usa `[\s\S]`, que coincide con todos los espacios y los caracteres que no son espacios (o sea, **con cualquier caracter**).

**Expresión regular**

```
/Incident:([\s\S]*?)\tDescriptio/g
```

<kbd>[demo en regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dR0yI8/1)</kbd>

**Código**

```js
var resultados_texto = "Bla Incident: incidente\nen\nvarias\nlineas\n\tDescription";
var m;

// Prueba para el ejemplo original
var re = /Incident:(.*)\tDescriptio/g; 
console.log('Regex:', re);
var resultado = [];
while ((m = re.exec(resultados_texto)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
    re.lastIndex++;
  }
  
  resultado.push(m); //agregar el resultado al array
}
console.log('Resultado:', resultado);

// -----------------------------

// Expresión regular propuesta
var re = /Incident:([\s\S]*?)\tDescriptio/g; 
console.log('Regex:', re);
var resultado = [];
while ((m = re.exec(resultados_texto)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
    re.lastIndex++;
  }
  
  resultado.push(m); //agregar el resultado al array
}
console.log('Resultado:', resultado);
```